# Positioning scroll bar adjacent to child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The following script positions the scroll bar on the far right of the screen.  I wish it to be located directly right of the table.

Note that all style on this table is being added by JavaScript.

I thought I would just get the table width using `var width=$('.body').width();`, and apply it to the enclosing `<div>` using `$('.container').width(width);`

Problem is the scroll bar occupies space, and inappropriately compresses the table.

I can arbitrarily add some extra width, however, am concerned that it might be different for different browsers.

How would this best be accomplished?  Thank you

```
<body>
    <div id="myTable">
        <table class="header"></table>
        <div class="container" style="overflow-y:auto; height:40px;">
            <table class="body">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px">ddd</td>
                        <td style="width:110px">ccc</td>
                        <td style="width:120px">42</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ddd</td>
                        <td>ccc</td>
                        <td>42</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ddd</td>
                        <td>ccc</td>
                        <td>42</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <table class="footer"></table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You want to scroll the table with a scroll bar? why not just add a set height and use `overflow-x: scroll`

Comment: I am looking for just a vertical scroll bar.  I did set a height to the <div>  Should it have been on the <table>?

Comment: I would go with what Andy suggested. If this is not your solution, I can't understand the question at all.

Comment: @user1032531 No you shouldn't use a `DIV` nor a `height` attribute. Read the comment by Andy, read it twice and then try to understand what was said

Comment: They want to keep the scroll bar from occupying space in the width of the div. I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @feela.  Read it 8 times!  Tried to make a jsfiddle, but it is down.  Please see http://tapmeister.com/test/scroll.html.  The top table has a scroll bar, but is positioned at the far right.  What am I doing wrong for the bottom scroll bar.  Thanks

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle.  Then I need to make the DIV bigger.  Is it possible to get the scroll width using JavaScript?

Comment: @Andy.  Can you please elaborate.  See http://tapmeister.com/test/scroll.html for my attempt to do so.

Comment: @user1032531 `overflow-y:scroll; height:60px;`on the div seems to work for me, unless we aren't clear on what you want to achieve

Comment: @Andy.  Yes, it works, but it is located on the inside right edge of div.container.  I wish it to be located on the outside right edge of table.body.  Since table.body's width is fixed, and div.container's width is not and thus extends to it's parent <body>, the scroll bar is positioned way to the right.

Comment: @user1032531 Can you draw a picture of what you want it like? I don't understand

Comment: @Andy.  Yes, I can make a picture.  See http://tapmeister.com/test/scroll.html.  The problem on how I did this is I kept on manually changing the div's width until I got to width:360px.  Might be different for other browsers, will need to change if table changed, etc, etc, so a bad approach.

Comment: @user1032531 That's because the div will automatically stretch to 100% width unless you tell it otherwise. Whats wrong with specifying a width for the table?

Comment: @Andy.  Because the data in the table td's might change, and thus the table width might need to change.  Scratch that, maybe I am thinking of this wrong.  So, say I specify a width for the table.  How does this help.  Is it not the div's width that needs to be set to position the scroll bar in the right location.  But what should the div's width be set to?  The width of the table plus the width of the scroll bar where the scroll bar's width is based on the given browser.....

Comment: I think we're getting confused lol. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/te9qf/ You cant put a scroll bar on a table, you have to put it on a containing div, and make the table 100% width. I didn't set a width on the div, but you can set it to whatever and the table will fit inside it

Comment: @Andy, Thank you for all your help.  Still have the unknown desired width of the DIV.  For this case, it would need to be the width of the (3) columns (100px+110px+120px=330px) plus the width of the scroll bar (approximately 17px but I think based on browser).  I hoped there would be an easy solution, but it looks like I need to calculate the scroll bar width using JavaScript.